# Como fazer o @media print ignorar o @media max-width

Tags: css, css3

Estou com um problema no meu css que está gerando um layout "mobile" na hora de imprimir, eu tenho um `@media max-width` que faz o meu site responsivo, porém eu gostaria de ignora-lo no `@media print` e imprimir apenas o layout do desktop, teria alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, você fazer eles atuarem só na tela ou impressão usando `@media only` por exemplo

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   // somente tela
}
```

e depois

```
@media print {
   // impressão
}
```

Mais informações aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Deves fazer algo parecido com o seguinte:

```
@media not print {
     @media (min-width:500px) {
         /* o teu estilo */
     }
}
```

Isto basicamente executa como **(not print)** e **(min-width: 500px)**.

Espero ter ajudado. :)